Problem with Kafka setup in Kubernetes - Bootstrap broker disconnected
I've been following the steps to set up Confluent Platform with static host-based routing in Kubernetes. However, I'm encountering issues when trying to produce messages to a Kafka topic from an external client.
The error I'm seeing is:
WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker kafka.confluent.svc.cluster.local:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
ERROR Error when sending message to topic elastic-0 with key: null, value: 5 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic elastic-0 not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

It seems like there's a problem with connecting to the Kafka broker at kafka.confluent.svc.cluster.local:443.
I've followed the setup steps meticulously, including configuring TLS and generating certificates. However, I'm stuck at this point and unsure how to proceed.
These are the steps by followed from this readme-file
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Port 443 is normally TLS-secured HTTP.  Kafka by default uses port 9092.  Are you sure you have the right port?  If it's not just the port number, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Sorry I became busy with some other work
I found the mistake I was doing

I changed the bootstrap server url to kubernetes.docker.internal after changing the value for domain in the kafka config to kubernetes.docker.internal as well.
Then created the necessary certificated from first and now it is working.

Thank you for making an effort to solve my issue....
